# Primary/Default user on Debian in a VirtualBox is not a sudo user

Tags: debian, virtualbox, sudo

Hopefully the title isn't too confusing, but I am running a VirtualBox with Debian. I just created it and the default/primary user does not have any sudo privileges for some odd reason. I've been constantly looking online for help, but to no avail because most of the suggestions include using a Live CD. Not sure if I would be able to apply that method. Other suggestions for Ubuntu distros include a recovery mode but I don't remember seeing it during startup

Is there a way to add my primary user to the sudoers file?

I'm not too experienced in Debian or any other Linux distro, so explanations 'dumbed down' would be great

Comment: related, but not duplicate: [How can I make my own account a sudoers on VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1623376/how-can-i-make-my-own-account-a-sudoers-on-virtualbox)

Answer (score 3):

By default, Debian does not have sudo. Instead you have to `su` up to the root user and run commands that way.

To install sudo

### Su up as root

`$ su`

### Install sudo

`$ apt-get install sudo`

### Edit the sudoers file

`$ visudo`

Under the *User privilege specification* heading add in
`MyUSER ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, replacing MyUSER with the username you want.

Comment: `visudo: command not found`

Comment: Ah, weird. Under debian you have to switch to root with `su` and then `sudo visudo` or `sudo adduser <USER> sudo`.